# Looping the list to fetch the records based on the similar Id in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have res.list which as the information of all the records that i get from DB. Using for loop first i am trying to get the length of the array and then i need to add a record on the top of the grouped items as select all students as shown below

```
for(i=0;i<res.length;i++)
  {
     res.List[i].Student.Id // Here i am getting ID's of every record
     //Need to add select all to the records of same id suppose i have 1,2,3,4,5 ids then i need to       add select all for all the 5 record
  }
```

Sample Data in res.List

```
>0
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : "SJ"}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:"Abc"}
.Student : {Id:1,Name:"Student1"}

>1
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : ""}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:""}
.Student : {Id:5,Name:"Student6"}

>2
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : ""}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:""}
.Student : {Id:1,Name:"Student3"}

>3
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : ""}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:""}
.Student : {Id:5,Name:"Student5"}

>4
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : ""}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:""}
.Student : {Id:1,Name:"Student4"}

>5
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : ""}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:""}
.Student : {Id:7,Name:"Student9"}

>6
.School information : {RegId: 1,Name : ""}
.ParentInfo : {Id:0,Name:""}
.Student : {Id:7,Name:"Student11"}
```

Expected Result- Here i have student.Id of 1,5,7 so i need to show in this way

```
Select All Studentds //with check box
Student1
Student3
Student4

Select All Studentds //with check box
Student5
Student6

Select All Studentds //with check box
Student9
Student11
```

Comment: You should be using `res.List.length`. `res` is an object, `res.List` is the array you're looping over.

Comment: You could also use `res.List.forEach()`

Comment: can you show me with sample code with demo

Comment: Just change `i<res.length` to `i<res.List.length`. You really need me to write an answer for this trivial fix?

Comment: no i was asking the select all and unselect all for all the ids of same group can you review my expected result. right now i am getting all of the in select without select all. Now i need to separate them based on Id and append select all and unselect all

Comment: @barmar any update on the changes

Comment: select/unselect has nothing to do with my comment about the correct way to write the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is too trivial for Barmar, but here is an *actual* answer from me ;-)

```js
const res = { List:
[{"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : "SJ"},ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:"Abc"},Student:{Id:1,Name:"Student1"}},
 {"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : ""},  ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:""},   Student:{Id:5,Name:"Student6"}},
 {"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : ""},  ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:""},   Student:{Id:1,Name:"Student3"}},
 {"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : ""},  ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:""},   Student:{Id:5,Name:"Student5"}},
 {"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : ""},  ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:""},   Student:{Id:1,Name:"Student4"}},
 {"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : ""},  ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:""},   Student:{Id:7,Name:"Student9"}},
 {"School information":{RegId: 1,Name : ""},  ParentInfo:{Id:0,Name:""},   Student:{Id:7,Name:"Student11"}}]};

const result = res.List.reduce((a,c,i)=>{
    (a[c.Student.Id]??=[]).push(c.Student.Name);
    return a;
},{});

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML=
 Object.values(result).map(grp=>
 '<div><label>Select All Studentds <input type="checkbox" class="group"></label><br>'
 +grp.map(s=>`<label><input type="checkbox">${s}</label>`).join("<br>")+'</div>').join("");
 
document.querySelectorAll(".group").forEach(cb=>
  cb.addEventListener("click",()=>cb.closest("div").querySelectorAll(" [type=checkbox]").forEach(c=>c.checked=cb.checked)))
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

I have now equipped the snippet with some HTML and some checkboxes. I hope this is what you had in mind.

Comment: i need the data with select all students for each id (Checkbox to select all the records/unselect all the records of the group)  this grouping is already achieved can you see my expected result once

Comment: any update on the change

Comment: When I select student1, student3 and student4 individually the select all should also getting checked automatically and the label name should get changed to unselect all know only thas missing

Comment: Hey @Bhavya, a belated welcome to Stack overflow! Yes, I did create some code for you but I would like to point out to you that this is not a free coding service. :D - You are actually expected to show some effort too!